# Can't play mp4 hosted on Win Server in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, iis, video, video.js

I have the same mp4 file which is hosted on two servers: the first is with Apache/Debian and the second with IIS/Win7. To play video I use video.js. When I try to play video from Debian - everything is Ok, video is played. But when from Win7 - fail. I only see an error in console " Video Error[object Object]". I have googled and tried everything what I could but can't make IE to play video from the server with Win7.

I added needed MIME type in IIS: .mp4 video/mp4

Besides that evetything is good with playing in Chrome.

Could anyone point me what can be wrong with IIS?

Comment: Show us your video.js. At least the part where it creates the player and loads your mp4 file.

Comment: It's the same like on http://videojs.com/